# SBT cannot resolve class declared in src/main/scala in a src/test/scala test class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to make my own custom CSV reader. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14 with sbt and specs2 test framework.

The class I declared in `src/main` is as follows:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream

import scala.io.Source

class CSVStream(filePath:String) {
  val csvStream = Source.fromInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath)).getLines()
  val headers = csvStream.next().split("\\,", -1)
}
```

The content of the test file in `src/test` is as follows:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

object CSVStreamSpec {

  val csvSourcePath = getClass.getResource("/csv_source.csv").getPath
}

class CSVStreamSpec extends Specification {
  import CSVStreamLib.CSVStreamSpec._

  "The CSV Stream reader" should {
    "Extract the header" in {
      val csvSource = CSVStream(csvSourcePath)
    }
  }
}
```

The `build.sbt` file contains the following:

```
name := "csvStreamLib"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "2.4.15" % "test")

parallelExecution in Test := false
```

The error I am getting when I type test is as follows:

```
[error] /Users/raiyan/IdeaProjects/csvStreamLib/src/test/scala/csvStreamSpec.scala:18: not found: value CSVStream
[error]       val csvSource = CSVStream(csvSourcePath)
[error]                       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 23 s, completed 30-Dec-2014 07:44:46
```

How do I make the CSVStream class accessible to the CSVStreamSpec class in the test file?

**Update:**

I tried it with sbt in the command line. The result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `new` keyword. Without it, the compiler looks for the *companion object* named `CSVStream`, not the class. Since there is none, it complains. Add `new` and it'll work.

Comment: I think everyone learning Scala trips over this a few times.  Wouldn't it be cool if the error message included something like "I see a *type* by that name, but not a *value*."